# typeahead-template-url not rendering {{}} expressions in template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this Angular.js UI-Bootstrap issue. The `typeahead-template-url="typeahead/bind-node.html"` is not rendering the expression's `{{}}` in the typeahead template. I am not sure why. In Chromium debugger, I verified this in element inspector where there are literal `{{match}}` instead of the expression evaluated.

I also have verified with 'console.log()' that the objects being returned to `getNodeLabel($viewValue)` are good.

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="label" name="label" ng-model="$parent.node.id" typeahead-min-length="1"
       placeholder="Node Name / Label"
       typeahead-template-url="typeahead/bind-node.html" style="width:350px;"
       typeahead-editable="false"
       typeahead="dropDownItem as dropDownItems.label for dropDownItem in getNodeLabel($viewValue)"
       typeahead-loading="loadingNodeLabels" class="form-control" required>
<i ng-show="loadingNodeLabels" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

---

typeahead html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="bind-node.html">
 <a>
 {{match}}
 <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query" class="ng-binding">
 <i>{{match.label}}</i>
 <h1>{{match}}</h1>
 </span>
 </a>
</script>
```

Comment: mismatch  `dropDownItem` vs `dropDownItems`  ??

Comment: When you say it isn't "rendering the expression's {{}}", are you getting white spaces or `{{}}` in the HTML?

Comment: I am getting actual ascii braces `{{}}` in the html.

Comment: That's very strange. Normally that means the HTML template is not being compiled, otherwise you shouldn't see any `{{}}` in the rendered HTML. Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: No, I can't.... doesnt UI bootstrap `typeahead` have it's own directive/controller in it's code? Could there be something wrong in this area that would cause the template not to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="bind-node.html"` needs to be `id="typeahead/bind-node.html"`